# Declare View Name for NavigationView but don't show it swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a view that uses a `NavigationLink` to navigate to another view. Normally, if the first view has a `NavigationTitle`, then the back button for the second will show the name. However, I don't want to show a `NavigationTitle` in the first view. Is there a way to still get the `NavigationView` to recognize the title of my first view without declaring a title that will show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.navigationBarHidden(true)` on your first view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Open DetailView", destination: DetailView())
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is DetailView")
            .navigationBarTitle("Detail")
    }
}
```